# Postgres - Cast Column to Type or Null If Unable To Cast

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres table I loaded from a mongodb collection in postgres.
Although the postgres column is of type 'bigint', there are rows that are larger than the max big int, so when I try to update another table from this table, it errors out. There are also bigint columns with illegal characters, such as "_2131441" which I cleared via

```
WHERE col_name !~ '^([0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*|[.][0-9]+)$';
```

How can I force cast an entire column to be valid according to it's type, and set it to null/none if otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```
CASE WHEN col_name !~ '^(\+|-)?[[:digit:]]+$'
     THEN NULL::bigint
     WHEN col_name::numeric NOT BETWEEN -9223372036854775808 AND 9223372036854775807
     THEN NULL::bigint
     ELSE col_name::bigint
END
```

Note that `bigint` is an integer and does not allow a decimal separator.